# Deleted iTunes app on iPhone with no backup

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios

When I was loading the new iOS 7 to my iPhone, it glitched during the process. I had tapped the screen several times and I sat and watched it catch up, shake, confirm and deleted my iTunes app.

I have the App Store but can't get to the iTunes application. Nothing is letting me restore. I do not have a computer with the iTunes app synced/backed up. My computer is down since I set up iTunes and I'm using a spare on which I'm unable to download iTunes.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to delete the standard applications on an iPhone. Did you try to search for it (swipe down for the search field)?

Comment: sorry how so I find the search it used to be at the top of ont of the screens but now I cant seem to find it

Comment: Swipe down in the middle of the screen. And which app are you missing actually?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes app cannot be deleted from the iPhone. In any case, you probably don't need the iTunes app but what you are trying to access is the Music app instead - which lists all your iPhone songs and playlists. Simply search for Music and open the app. You should see your music intact.